# (movieclip1).gotoAndPlay from inside another movieclip(movieclip2) not working

Tags: flash, actionscript, undefined, symbols, movieclip

I have a movieclip on stage that is a black screen and nothing else. Just a black rectangle with frames that have frame instance names. The overall instance name of this black screen is simply "BlackScreen".

What I am trying to do is do BlackScreen.gotoAndPlay("BSL") from another movieclip that's on the same stage in a different layer of the stage. The "BSL" is one of the frame instance names.

This seems like it would work, as all I am trying to do is play some frames. But whenever I test the project, it gives me this for all the instances I use BlackScreen.gotoAndPlay("BSL"):

**Symbol 'Darkened Code', Layer 'Head', Frame 1119, Line 1, Column 1    1120: Access of undefined property BlackScreen.**

What I'm assuming is that a movieclip can't detect other movieclips? Or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access BlackScreen through `_root` (as2) or `root` (as3). When you write code on the timeline of a movieclip, the "scope" of the code is that of the movieclip and not the main stage. By trying to access `BlackScreen` here, it will look for `BlackScreen` *inside* the `Darkened Code` movieclip, you need to tell it explicitly to look on the main stage using `root`

eg.

```
root.BlackScreen.gotoAndPlay("BSL")
```